# Handling overflow in fraction multiplication

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, overflow

Say I want to multiply `x` by `(3/8)`. So I can get the result using shift operation as follows (The result should round toward zero):

```
int Test(int x) {
    int value = (x << 1) + x;
    value = value >> 3;
    value =  value + ((x >> 31) & 1); 
    return  value;
}
```

So I'll have `4` in `Test(11)` and `-3` in `Test(-9)`. The problem is, because I am doing the multiplication first, I'll have an overflow at some ranges and in those cases I won't get the correct value:

```
Test(0x80000000)  // returns -268435455, but it should be -268435456
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You already posted that question some day(s) ago. And I (and others) told you you invoke _undefined_ and _implementation defined behaviour_. And the overflow also invokes undefined behaviour, so all bets are off.

Comment: You either need to use a variable bigger than an `int`, e.g. `long` assuming that `long` has more bits on your system. Or you can split the `int` into two `int`s, each of which has half the bits, and then do the math.

Comment: @user3386109: `long` only has more bits on POSIX64 and is not really portable. Better to use fixed-width types. These also have well-defined representation, thus signed/unsigned conversion behaviour.

Comment: @Olaf Note: many systems aside from POSIX64 have `long` wider than `int`:  Embedded platforms, DOS, etc.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for mentioning that again. Please note that undefined behavior doesn't really change my question, and also this is not the same question. I still want to handle this overflow (please read the title). Moreover since I asked this question it simply means you previous comments weren't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix this? (overflow at some ranges)

Divide by 8 first.

For each multiple of 8, the result increases by 3, exactly.  So all that remains is to figure out 3/8 of numbers -7 to 7, which OP's `test()` can handle.  Simplifications possible.

```
int Times3_8(int x) {
  int div8 = x/8;
  int value = div8*3 + Test(x%8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x/8*3 + x%8*3/8;
}
```

http://ideone.com/2wGtpl

Inspired by **chux**'s answer: the key is to divide by 8 first (to sacrifice precision for range) and use a second term to handle the quantization error (correct for the error in a smaller range).

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to handle the high and low halves differently.  For the high half of `x`, shift right 3 first, then multiply by 3.  For the low half, multiply by 3 and then shift right by 3.  Then add the two results together.  That should work for the positive case.  For negative numbers, you will need to tweak this a bit.